# Change of Basis and coordinate vector for polynomial spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, orthogonal-polynomials

In this problem we have the polynomial vector space$P_{2}$ is all polynomials with degree smaller or equal to 2 and the scalar product is defined as: $$\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(t)q(t) dt$$. \

I need to first find an orthonormal Basis Q for the Vectorspace $P_{2}$. I did that using the Gram-Schmidth process and got the following for Q. $$\{ {1\over \sqrt 2}, {3\over 2}x, {45\over8}(x^2-1/3)\}$$. \ 
noe I need to find the transformation Matrix to transform the coordinate vectors from $P_{2}$ to Q. I'm not sure how to do that. I got the following for T. is this correct? please help. thanks.

More general, how can I find the transformation matrix from a basis $P_{2}$ to Q? this confuses me everytime!

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
        1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 3/2 & 0 \\
        -15/8 & 0 & 45/8 \\
        \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct, but it seems that you have forgot that the norm is the square root of the inner product: $||f||=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$. The correct  answer is that the orthonormal basis, with your inner product, is:
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x,\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}(3x^2-1)\right\}
$$

Note that these are Legendre Polynomials normalized in a different way than usual.

You can correct the matrix with these corrected polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Assuming that the orthonormal basis that I wrote is correct, is the transformation matrix also right according to that orthonormal basis?

Comment: The structure of the matrix is correct, but you have to change the entries according to the correct basis.

Comment: got it, thanks :)